# Select specific rows MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I select specific rows in a MySQL Table? So instead of `select`ing `... ORDER BY date` can I do something like `SELECT * FROM Posts FROM(5) TO(10) ORDER BY date DESC` where I would be selecting Posts 5 to 10 in the descending order?

Comment: 1000 rep and no searches on google before? hmm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous. There are two possibilities:

1. You want **only part of the results** to be retrieved from the database, for example from the 5th one to the 10th one:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 6 OFFSET 4
   ```

   which will skip the 4 first results and given you next 6 results (beginning with 5th from the original set and ending with 10th from the original set).
2. You want results **with specific IDs** between `5` (inclusive) and `10` (inclusive):

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` BETWEEN 5 AND 10 ORDER BY `date` DESC
   ```

   or (which can be useful if the list of IDs is not the whole range):

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` IN (5,6,7,8,9,10) ORDER BY `date` DESC
   ```

   but this last example is only to show you different way of picking "specific" rows.

Answer (score 3):

use limit:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5, 5
```

http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: `LIMIT` goes **after** `ORDER BY`, i.e. at the end of the statement ([see the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `limit` operator in mysql to do this. Ex: `SELECT * FROM  posts LIMIT 5 , 5`;

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Syntax which is more readable in my opinion:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
```

The first number indicates the number of results returned, the second one defines the offset from where to begin with.

If you use the `LIMIT 5,5` it's the other way round.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY date DESC' at line 1

Answer (score -1):

You can use the limit:

```
SELECT * FROM tabel ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5,5
```

(5th till 10th record based on descending date).

Comment: Please read that help content regarding code inclusion in the answer

Comment: worthless giving a -1 for that tho.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM Posts ORDER BY date DESC limit 5, 10
```

Comment: Please read that help content regarding code inclusion in the answer

Comment: This is incorrect. `ORDER BY` should go after `LIMIT`. Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)